# SSLITE ERROR - using Websphere and calling a webservice with apache client 3.x

Tags: ssl, websphere, apache-httpclient-4.x

I do not understand the origin of this issue: 
com.ibm.sslite.d: reason=2; alert=40; exception=null

It happens when i call:

```
int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
```

It might be related to the SSL protocol and maybe websphere is quite old and incompatible.

```
12:56:46 [sid=] [uid=] [oid=] - ERROR com.darty.ecom.frontoffice.newespaceclient.core.service.cev.CevProxyConnection - CEV > STACK TRACE > 
com.ibm.sslite.d: reason=2; alert=40; exception=null
    at com.ibm.sslite.m.a(m.java:50)
    at com.ibm.sslite.t.b(t.java:113)
    at com.ibm.sslite.t.a(t.java:43)
    at com.ibm.sslite.a.read(a.java:7)
    at com.ibm.jsse.a.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1115)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1373)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1832)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1590)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at com.darty.ecom.frontoffice.newespaceclient.core.service.cev.CevProxyConnection.executeMethod(CevProxyConnection.java:137)
```

---

the same error in the integration environmenent is a little different and says:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are using and doing. Have you considered using a different webservice client like axis/2 or jax-ws? What happens when you call the service with soapui?

Answer (score 0):

That means the server-side sent a TLS alert telling you the handshake failed. (alert#40) You'll need to debug the *why* on the server -- maybe it requries TLS client authentication, maybe your client only uses ancient protocols/ciphers or visa versa.